# Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.using bool & unsigned short

Tags: c++, oop, sfml

So im trying to set up my code neatly doing what i normally do but now i am getting this error when running

```
First-chance exception at 0x01313D46 in Server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

Visual studio also tells me in the locals box that it is unable to read memory for

```
unsigned short port
bool listening
```

Here is the Header and Cpp where the error is occuring

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML\Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class NetServer
{
private:
    bool listening;
    unsigned short port;
public:
    NetServer(void);
    ~NetServer(void);

    void InitNetServer();

    void SetListening(bool a)
    {
        a = listening;
    }
    bool IsListening()
    {
        return listening;
    }

    void SetPort(unsigned short a)
    {
        a = port;
    }
    int GetPort()
    {
        return port;
    }
};
```

The debug breaks when it gets too SetListening(bool a) and then if i take that out it breaks at SetPort

Here is my Cpp

```
#include "NetServer.h"

sf::TcpListener listener;
sf::TcpSocket client;

NetServer::NetServer(void)
{
    //listener.listen(21025);
    //cout << "listening" << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        if (listener.accept(client) == sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            cout << "New connection received from " << client.getRemoteAddress() << endl;
        }
    }
}

NetServer::~NetServer(void)
{
    SetPort(NULL);
    SetListening(false);
}

void NetServer::InitNetServer()
{
    cout << "Initialising the NetServer" << endl;
    SetListening(true);
    SetPort(45000);

    listener.listen(GetPort());
    cout << "NetServer Initialised : Listening on Port "<< GetPort() << endl;
}
```

Here is my only other class this is also called in GameServer.h/cpp

```
    #include "GameServer.h"

GameServer::GameServer()
{
    Run();
}

GameServer::~GameServer(void)
{
    DestroyNetServer();
    Exit();
}

void GameServer::Run()
{
    cout << "Initialising the engine." << endl;

    /* Initialise stuff here */
    _NetServer->InitNetServer();
    /* Finish initialisation */

    SetGameRunning(true);

    while(GetGameRunning() == true)
    {
        _NetServer;
    }
}

void GameServer::Exit()
{
    exit(0);
}

NetServer & GameServer::GetNetServer()
{
    if(_NetServer == 0) throw exception ("Null Game Server");
    return *_NetServer;
}

void GameServer::CreateNetServer()
{
    _NetServer = new NetServer();
}

void GameServer::DestroyNetServer()
{
    delete _NetServer;
}




#pragma once

#include "NetServer.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class NetServer;

class GameServer
{
public:
    GameServer();
    ~GameServer(void);

    void Run();
    void Exit();

    void SetGameRunning(bool running)
    {
        gameRunning = running;
    }
    bool GetGameRunning()
    {
        return gameRunning;
    }

    void CreateNetServer();
    NetServer & GetNetServer();
    void DestroyNetServer();

private:
    bool gameRunning;

    NetServer * _NetServer;
};
```

Comment: 0xcccccccc means you are using an uninitialized variable as a pointer... Without seeing a more complete example of your code, it's hard to see where it is - don't see anything obvious in the code you have posted [which is not unusual, about 80% of "What's wrong in my code" shows the code that isn't the problem].

Comment: Probably not related to your crash but `SetListening` and `SetPort` look wrong.  Shouldn't they be assigning `member = arg` rather than `temp_copy_of_arg = uninitialised_member`

Comment: `SetPort` takes an `unsigned short` and you're giving it `NULL`. The fact that it 100% doesn't compile when you substitute that `NULL` for `nullptr` should be an indication that it's the wrong thing to use.

Comment: @Mats Peresson I posted this pieces of code because thats what VS is telling me here is the error also i am only calling the function in the header where i get the error in the NetServer.cpp then just referencing the constructor in another class

Comment: Right, so if I do `printf("%s", 42);`, you'd suggest that I post the code for `printf`, because it says "Access violation in printf, address = 0x0000002a"?

Comment: You can set up Visual Studio to break into the debugger when an exception is raised. With this being an SEH exception go to *Debug* -> *Exceptions...* and enable the check-box *Win32 Exceptions* (or just the specific one for an access violation).

Comment: I have already enabled all the exceptions

Comment: @BumblebeeStudio I can almost assure you that the pointer you're using for your NetServer object access (i.e. somewhere you have `p->InitNetServer(...)`) is invalid. The compiler will happily generate code that pushes your bad pointer as `this`, then invoke the non-virtual `InitNetServer()` method. You're seeing the access violation in the two setters because those are the first places you're actually writing to memory that you don't own.

Comment: With your updated code, set your breakpoint on `_NetServer->InitNetServer(...)` and inspect that pointer *before* the invoke.

Comment: `_NetServer` appears to be a pointer that isn't being initialized - I suspect that is what the problem is. Maybe you don't actually want `_NetServer` to be a pointer?

Comment: I concur with @MatsPetersson. If the lifetime of `_NetServer` is supposed to be as long as the `GameServer` object, you may wish to forego the pointer entirely and just use an member instance.

Answer (score 0):

Run is called in the constructor and nobody is initializing the _NetServer pointer.
So you are trying to call a method of an uninitiated object.
Add CreateNetServer before calling Run()

```
GameServer::GameServer()
{
  CreateNetServer()
  Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never initialize `listening` or `port`. Even your setter methods won't help you, because the assignment is flipped around (you're assigning values to the local parameter, rather than copying the value to your instance member).

For example:

```
void SetListening(bool a)
{
    a = listening;
}
```

Should probably be:

```
void SetListening(bool a)
{
    listening = a;
}
```

Besides fixing your setters, to fix the problem of never assigning `listening` or `port` values, you need to do that in the [constructor initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html):

```
NetServer::NetServer(void)
  : listening(false)
  , port(0)
{
    //listener.listen(21025);
    //cout << "listening" << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        if (listener.accept(client) == sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            cout << "New connection received from " << client.getRemoteAddress() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have no idea what the intent of this code even is, but it looks wrong:

```
while(GetGameRunning() == true)
{
    _NetServer;
}
```